# Can't start Neo4J (3.0.1) after closing laptop on Windows 10

Tags: neo4j

I'm new to Neo4j and started to create my first graph database on the default database. I've added less than 40 nodes and approximately 60 relations.

Toward to the end of this work, I noticed that the response time in Neo4j browser is getting slower. I decided to exit Neo4j browser and stop the server. The server did not stop immediately and I close the laptop after waiting 10 minutes.

When I try to start the server on windows 10 today, I get the following error message:

*Starting Neo4j failed: Failed to transition component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.pagecache.PageCacheLifecycle@284149b9' from STOPPED to SHUTTING_DOWN. Please see attached cause exception*

Where do I find the mentioned attachment and how can recover from this error? Did I cause the database to corrupt?
Thanks,

Comment: What do you see on the Neo4J logs?

Comment: Recovery required from position LogPosition{logVersion=0, byteOffset=137478}

Comment: Sorry, I prematurely hit the button. The following are in the debug.log  "Exception occurred while starting the datasource. Attempting to close things down." and "Couldn't close neostore after startup failure". I decided to delete everything and start fresh. However, I really appreciate your help. Thank you